# How to plot line segments on a map using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, cartopy

I'm trying to plot line segments on a map (preferably Orthographic projection) with different colours depending on a variable's value. I have a list of consecutive lat/lon positions of a ship, and distance measured between these consecutive positions.

So, I'm trying to plot line segments between pos1(lat1/lon1) and pos2(lat2/lon2), pos2(lat2/lon2) and pos3(lat3/lon3), so on till [n-1] positions, colour depending on the distance value. When I run this code, I get weird line segments mis-located.

[image: plot]

I found similar questions on SO but none plotting on geographic axes. What am I doing wrong? I tried many things, changing longitude to 0-360, changing central longitude of the PlateCarree proj. Please help. Thanks

data file: [ship tracks](https://github.com/prt31/rawObs/blob/master/ship_tracks_distances.csv)

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


shp_trk=pd.read_csv('/Users/prt/ship_tracks_distances.csv')

y = np.asarray(shp_trk['Plat'])
x = np.asarray(shp_trk['Plong'])
dis = np.asarray(shp_trk['dis'])

#segments
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[20,10])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))
#ax.set_extent([lonmin,lonmax,latmin,latmax],crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
#ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=0, central_longitude=190))

ax.stock_img()
ax.coastlines()

plt.title('Salt Lake City\n'
          'MS',fontdict={'fontsize':16})


norm = plt.Normalize(dis.min(), dis.max())
lc = LineCollection(segments,antialiaseds=(1,), cmap='viridis', norm=norm)
# Set the values used for colormapping
lc.set_array(dis)
lc.set_linewidth(2)
#lc.set_edgecolors('red')
line = ax.add_collection(lc)
fig.colorbar(line, ax=ax)


#Pearl Harbour
plt.plot(-157.9491, 21.3618, 'yo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(-155, 18, 'Pearl Harbour', fontdict={'fontsize':16}, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
#San Diego
plt.plot(-117.1625, 32.715, 'yo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(-117, 33, 'San Diego', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
#Brisbane Harbour
plt.plot(153.2469,-27.2491, 'yo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(153, -27.2, 'Brisbane', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())


plt.show()
```

But, when I plot this on cartesian grid, it works fine.

Comment: I think you need to add the transform when you create your line collection; something like: `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()` or `transform=ccrs.Geodetic()`

Comment: Thanks so much for lightning fast answer @tmdavison that did the trick, a side question: How do the set the map extent, such that area between west-coast of America and east coast of Australia (crossing the dateline) are only visible?

Comment: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/geoaxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.set_extent

Comment: Thanks! set the map extent.